# Button overlaps the textview

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am just beginning android programming. Facing an error.
Problem is that the button covers the text in the textview.
I tried to put android:orientation="vertical".........but this android:orientation is not present in the xml...i mean it is not showing in the methods suggested.........Please help me hot to resolve the problem.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".StartingPoint" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" 
    android:textSize="45sp" 
    android:gravity="center"
    />

<Button
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add one" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are using a relative layout and haven't specified what the button is relative to. I would recommend changing to a different layout (ie linear layout). There is a good tutorial here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html

Comment: @NutterzUK.....sorry i could not understand ur answer.........i got the point.....Thanks a lot....:)